# Set app level proxy

Tags: android, proxy, sdk

I'm trying to create some sort of SDK that we intercept each request from my app regardless of which HTTP client it's using (be it native HttpURLConnection, OkHttp, Retrofit etc.). And including traffic from third-party libraries like Firebase Analytics etc.

I need to intercept and check few parameters then decide whether to allow or block current request.

I don't want to use any Custom VPN as it has some side effects like showing system level Notification and all traffic from the user device.

Is it possible to capture all requests by setting `app level` proxy? 
If possible, How to achieve it in code?

Comment: Based on the forum rules is a valid question. why downvote?

Comment: hey, old question I know, but did you made it in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Retrofit
The retrofit will save your development time, And also you can keep your code in developer friendly. Retrofit has given almost all the API's to make a server call and to receive a response. internally they also use GSON to do the parsing. you can go through this [link](https://vickychijwani.me/retrofit-vs-volley/) you will get more info Alos you can see the [difference](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/is-retrofit-faster-than-volley-the-answer-may-surprise-you-4379bc589d7c) with other libs

Comment: you can add Interceptor to varification

Comment: how? are you talking about Retrofit interceptors?

Comment: Retrofit interceptors only work for requests made with retrofit. how to intercept requests made with native HttpClient by third-party libraries like Firebase Analytics?

Answer (score 2):

You could give a try to implement a custom VPN with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService. With this you should be able to control which traffic is allowed to access the internet and which not. As you wrote, that you'll create an SDK, the implementors should know the side effects of VPNs in apps (ongoing system notification, every traffic is routet through that VPN, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, VPN has side effects that why I didn't go with VPN. I only want all traffic from a single app which uses my SDK. Is that possible with any work around?

Comment: Have you tried [URLStreamHandlerFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLStreamHandlerFactory) already? Maybe it covers also other libraries like Volley and Retrofit.

Comment: Not yet. I will try and get back to you

Comment: Can you specify how to make use of URLStreamHandlerFactory class?

Comment: You set it via [`URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory(java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory)). However, the docs say, that you can call it only once per lifetime of a JVM. So, it works on Android, you should call that function before anything else, for instance in the Application class constructor.